# Select from table with two conditions

Tags: sql

I'm stuck with a query and I'd need some help.

I need to select values from a table which meets two conditions from other table, for example:

```
Select * from table1 
where ID =  (select ID from table2) 
AND value = (select value from table2)
```

So, if I'd need only one value from the table, I could query:

```
Select * from table1 where ID =  (id1) AND value = (value1)
```

The only solution that I know is using IN, but it wouldn't be the requested solution.

I need something similar to this, but counting that the data returned by table2 is not only one row, but multiple.

Could somebody give me some clue on how to find this?

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please add the tag for the database you are actually using.

Comment: is the ID and value in table1 are foreign keys of table2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `exists`:

```
Select *
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t2.id = t1.id and t2.value = t1.value
             );
```

This is ANSI standard syntax, so it should work in any database.  Some databases support this syntax:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where (t1.id, t1.value) in (select t2.id, t2.value from table2 t2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `AND` and `OR`

```
select * 
from table1 
where (ID =  (id1) AND value = (value1)) 
OR (ID =  (id2) AND value = (value2))
```

Each check must be added in brackets. This allows all results matching the pairs ID and VALUE to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from 
table1 inner join table2 on
(table1.ID = table2.ID and  
table1.value = table2.value) ;
```

> Since as far as I can understand , you just need to select every rows from `table1` where `ID` and `value` in `table1` equals `ID` and `value` in `table2`. So you just need `inner join` which joins `table1` and `table2` checking the condition.